# Converting QGIS 3.6 Templates for use in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-2, print-templates

How do I convert QGIS 3.6 Templates for use in QGIS 2.18?

I have found plenty of stuff on converting the opposite way around.

Comment: I doubt that you can. However, try this: create a simple template in QGIS 3.6. Create an identical template in 2.18. Open both files in a text editor and figure out what's different. Use that information to edit your 3.6 templates to be compatible with 2.18.

Comment: Sad, but time to say goodbye to QGIS 2. It's EOL and no longer supported. It is highly recommended to migrate to QGIS 3.